# SERP states "Parked", but it's not

Tags: seo, search-results, migration

We're in the process of migrating our domain from A to B. This is the first time I have done this, so I started researching best practices.

Going straight to the source, I watched Matthew Cutts "Changing your website's domain name". Watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wATxftE8ooE

I know it's a bit dated (2011), but it seemed quite reasonable. Specific takes...

1. Remove the new domain from parked. (40 secs)
2. Add a page to the new site with one or two paragraphs stating (something like) "This is going to be the new site". (1:10)
3. Google will try to detect domains that transition from parked to aid migration. (1:16)
4. Do this process slowly at first. (1:25)

I began this process - purchased the new domain and established the one-page summary of intention. I intended to sit on it for about a month before initiating any migration.

Google has since indexed the site. SERP states:

```
<domain> is Parked
<domain> is Parked. Thank you for visiting <domain>. A parked domain means that the owner / registrant has not yet published their website or pointed the...
```

Before I purchased the domain, it did not appear in SERP at all.

Needless to say, my page does not say the above. Google has added this summary to SERP.

**Is this a mistake? Any insights you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely explanation to me is that Google crawled this page a long time ago, and the cache is out of date.

I would use Google Search Console to inspect the url. Click "test live URL", then "view tested page". If that shows your real page and not the parking page, then click "request indexing" to ask google to re-crawl the page. Within a few days, the updated page content should be showing in Google Search.

Comment: Good answer. I already requested indexing. Maybe it's a wait and see what happens scenario.